# How to use apply-templates to call the template and pass the one attribute as the parameter

Tags: xslt

I have an XML similar to below

```
<siteMap>
    <siteMapNode id="1232" title="Home" url="www.google.com" depth="0" use_as_default="Yes">
        <siteMapNode id="" title="Resourses" url="" depth="1" blue_button="False">
            <siteMapNode id="" title="Project" url="" depth="2" blue_button="False" />
            <siteMapNode id="" title="Music" url="" depth="2" blue_button="False" />
            <siteMapNode id="" title="Vedio" url="" depth="2" blue_button="False" />
            <siteMapNode id="" title="Party" url="" depth="2" blue_button="False" /></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Somewhere in the XSLT i want to write code something like this

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul class="toplevel-menu group">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="EXPERSSION1" />
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="EXPRESSION2">
    <li>
    <a>
      <xsl:attribute name="title">
        <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </a>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
```

How to write the select="EXPERSSION1" and match="EXPRESSION2"

if i want to pass depth attribute in to the  
  Could somebody help me to construct the SELECT and match experssion in the scenerio.

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to write something like that -

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::*[@depth='2']">
                 <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="2" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

and use it as below

```
  <xsl:template match="sm:siteMapNode[@depth='2']"> 
         <xsl:if test="child::*">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="child::*">
         <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1" />   
         </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:if> 
          </xsl:template>
```

As i have to update one existing xslt and would prefer least changes to avoid breaking anything

Comment: What do you want the output to look like in this case? Are you trying to construct a nested list that matches the nesting of the original nodes or just a flat list of all the siteMapNodes in one go?

Comment: i want to display the nested <ul> and <li> means , if there is any child node then place new <ul> with <li>. <ul> <li>X</li> <li> Y <ul><li>a </li> </ul></ul> and nested onward.

Answer (score 0):

Xslt example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ul class="toplevel-menu group">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMap/siteMapNode">
                <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="1" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="siteMapNode">
        <xsl:param name="depth" />
        <li>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <!-- you could output the depth as attribute if you like, or use it some other way -->
                <xsl:attribute name="depth">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$depth" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@url" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
            </a>
            <xsl:if test="siteMapNode">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode">
                    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1" />
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:if>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT after update:

```
<xsl:template match="siteMapNode">
    <xsl:param name="depth" />
    <xsl:if test="$depth=2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="siteMapNode" mode="depth2"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="not($depth=2)">
        <!-- original template -->
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="siteMapNode" mode="depth2">
    <li depth="2"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for anwering .+1 for quick and nice reply. Could u please see my update above and suggest me accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the depth as a parameter, as every `siteMapNode` already has a `depth` attribute in the original XML so you can just use those.

```
<xsl:template match="sm:siteMap">
  <ul class="toplevel-menu group">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="sm:siteMapNode" />
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sm:siteMapNode">
  <li>
    <a title="{@title}" href="{@url}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </a>
    <!-- example of doing something with the depth attribute -->
    <xsl:text> at depth </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@depth"/>

    <xsl:if test="sm:siteMapNode">
      <ul><xsl:apply-templates select="sm:siteMapNode" /></ul>
    </xsl:if>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```